# Ruby 2.5, get first part of string depending substring

Tags: ruby, string, substring

What's the best way to get the first part of a string and remove the second part in Ruby ?
I know the first part to keep for each case

Examples:

```
"The Cuvée titi" => "The Cuvée"
"The Cuvée toto" => "The Cuvée"
"The Cuvée toto 1234" => "The Cuvée"
"1234 The Cuvée" => need to do nothing

"The wine 45 67" => "The wine"
"The wine not good" => " The wine"
"What's The wine ?" => need to do nothing
```

I tried many things, after reading some discussions, including:

- sub(), delete() => keep the second part, not the first
- even delete_suffix() of ruby 2.5 => not working in some cases
- string[0..x] => but works also when the start of the string is not good

Is a regex required ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand the problem.

If you know what the first part of the string is, and you only want to keep the first part of the string, there is no need to do anything, because you already know what the first part of the string is.

```rb
if string.start_with?(string_to_keep)
  string_to_keep
end
```

Comment: Really true. Sorry I think my night was too short ! ;)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: In the question, the OP gives a couple of examples where the string does not start with the search string. (#4 and #7.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what I did:

```
if string.start_with? string_to_keep
 new_string = string[0.. string_to_keep.length-1]
end
```

Surely not the best Ruby way, but working...

Answer (score 0):

```
key_string = "The Cuvée"
example_string_1 = "The Cuvée toto 1234"
example_string_2 = "1234 The Cuvée"
```

[`index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.6/String.html#method-i-slice) will return the first occurrence of the key string in your examples. You can then return everything including the first occurrence of your key string with [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.6/String.html#method-i-slice), like:

```
result1 = example_string_1.slice(0, example_string_1.index(key_string) + key_string.length)
 => "The Cuvée"

result2 = example_string_2.slice(0, example_string_2.index(key_string) + key_string.length)
 => "1234 The Cuvée"
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the objective could be viewed as removing the portion of the string that follows the given string.

```
def doit(str, given_str)
  str.gsub(/(?<=\b#{given_str}\b).*/, '')
end
```

```
given_str = "The Cuvée"
doit "The Cuvée titi", given_str       #=> "The Cuvée"
doit "The Cuvée toto", given_str       #=> "The Cuvée"
doit "The Cuvée toto 1234", given_str  #=> "The Cuvée"
doit "1234 The Cuvée", given_str       #=> "1234 The Cuvée"
```

```
given_str = "The wine"
doit "The wine 45 67", given_str       #=> "The wine"
doit "The wine not good", given_str    #=> "The wine"
doit "What's The wine?", given_str     #=> "What's The wine"
```

Note the question mark is removed in the last example.

For

```
given_str = "The wine"
```

the regular expression is

```
/(?<=\b#{given_str}\b).*/
  #=> /(?<=\bThe wine\b).*/
```

`(?<=\bThe wine\b)` is a *positive lookbehind*, meaning the the match is preceded by `"The wine"`, with word breaks on either side. `.*` matches zero or more characters, as many as possible, meaning the remaining characters in the string.

---

One more example for `given_str = "The wine"`:

```
doit "Go to The winery for The wine", given_str
  #=> "Go to The winery for The wine"
```

Without the word breaks (`\b`) this would be:

```
doit "Go to The winery for The wine", given_str
  #=> "Go to The wine"
```

The question does not tell me which result is desired.

Comment: Hello Cary. Thanks for the regex provided. The desired result is easier, because "The wine is always at the begining of my strings to analyze.

Comment: I don't follow. `"The Wine"` is not at the beginning of `"What's The wine ?"`. You say you have to "do nothing" for that. Does that mean that if the string does begin with `"The wine"` the entire string is to be returned? What is to be returned for `"The winery is there"`?

Comment: Hi Cary. Sorry for the delay. When the given string is not at begining, the full string needs to be returned. So "What's The Wine" => return "What's The Wine" AND "The Winery" => return "The Winery". So I need to check spaces. Alex.